# Overlapping events in a week view calendar

Tags: algorithm, events, calendar, overlapping

I'm searching for an efficient algorithm to display overlapping date events (start time -> end time) in a week view calendar. I looked at google calendar and how it manages overlapping events and it seems nice but I'd like to start with a known algorithm, if it exists.

Comment: Can you clarify which problem you are trying to solve? Please specify the input and desired output for the algorithm you want to develop.

Comment: No, and I abandoned this project

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visualization of calendar events. Algorithm to layout events with maximum width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311410/visualization-of-calendar-events-algorithm-to-layout-events-with-maximum-width)