# Place colliding elements next to each other

Tags: php, html

I'm creating some kind of calendar/agenda which shows the events for a specific day. Each event is displayed as an HTML element in a vertical hours grid. There could be multiple ("colliding") events at the same time, and in those cases the elements should be placed next to each other, horizontally, and have equal widths. E.g. four colliding events get the column value 4, in this way the width of 25%.

The tricky part is these colliding events. I thought I solved it, but some elements get the wrong number of columns.

There might be a better way to calculate the column count and placement - I'm open to suggestions.

**Sample image for current (wrong) result:**
[image]

**Relevant code:**

```
<?php
    class Calendar {
        const ROW_HEIGHT = 24;

        public $events = array();
        public $blocks = array();


        public function calculate_blocks() {
            foreach($this->events as $event) {

                // Calculate the correct height and vertical placement
                $top = $this->time_to_pixels($event->_event_start_time);
                $bottom = $this->time_to_pixels($event->_event_end_time);
                $height = $bottom - $top;

                // Abort if there's no height
                if(!$height) continue;

                $this->blocks[] = array(
                    'id' => $event->ID,
                    'columns' => 1,
                    'placement' => 0, // Column order, 0 = first
                    'css' => array(
                        'top' => $top,
                        'bottom' => $bottom, // bottom = top + height
                        'height' => $height
                    )
                );
            }

            $done = array();

            // Compare all the blocks with each other
            foreach($this->blocks as &$block) {
                foreach($this->blocks as &$sub) {

                    // Only compare two blocks once, and never compare a block with itself
                    if($block['id'] == $sub['id'] || (isset($done[$block['id']]) && in_array($sub['id'], $done[$block['id']])) || (isset($done[$sub['id']]) && in_array($block['id'], $done[$sub['id']]))) continue;
                    $done[$block['id']][] = $sub['id'];

                    // If the blocks are colliding
                    if(($sub['css']['top'] >= $block['css']['top'] && $sub['css']['top'] < $block['css']['bottom'])
                    || ($sub['css']['bottom'] >= $block['css']['top'] && $sub['css']['bottom'] < $block['css']['bottom'])
                    || ($sub['css']['top'] <= $block['css']['top'] && $sub['css']['bottom'] >= $block['css']['bottom'])) {

                        // Increase both blocks' columns and sub-block's placement
                        $sub['columns'] = ++$block['columns'];
                        $sub['placement']++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private function time_to_int($time) {

            // H:i:s (24-hour format)
            $hms = explode(':', $time);
            return ($hms[0] + ($hms[1] / 60) + ($hms[2] / 3600));
        }


        private function time_to_pixels($time) {
            $block = $this->time_to_int($time);

            return (int)round($block * self::ROW_HEIGHT * 2);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't think this is something that is to be solved in PHP. Here's [a nice JavaScript widget](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/) for it.

Comment: In this particular case it should be done at server-level. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Doesn't the cursor set to different positions when you're making these nested foreach with $this->blocks? Maybe you should check that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @SenseException. I've checked the cursor for each loop, and it's fine.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with 'nested loops' is to use 'read ahead' and 'while' loops, rather than 'foreach' loops. The issue is that you need to read the 'next record' at any point inside the current loop. The issue with 'foreach' is that they only read the 'next record' at the end of the loop.

Comment: Thanks @RyanVincent, can you link to any example? I doubt the loops themselves are the problem, though, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function calculate_blocks()
{
    $n          = count($events);
    $collumns   = array();
    $placements = array();

    // Set initial values.
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
    {
        $collumns[$i]   = 1;
        $placements[$i] = 0;
    }
    // Loop over all events.
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
    {
        $top1           = $this->time_to_pixels($events[$i]->_event_start_time);
        $bottom1        = $this->time_to_pixels($events[$i]->_event_end_time);

        // Check for collisions with events with higher indices.
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++)
        {
            $top2     = $this->time_to_pixels($events[$k]->_event_start_time);
            $bottom2  = $this->time_to_pixels($events[$k]->_event_end_time);
            $collides = $top1 < $bottom2 && $top2 < $bottom1;

            // If there is a collision, increase the collumn count for both events and move the j'th event one place to the right.
            if ($collides)
            {
                $collumns[$i]++;
                $collumns[$j]++;
                $placements[$j]++;
            }
        }

        $this->blocks[] = array(
            'id'        => $events[$i]->ID,
            'columns'   => $collumns[$i],
            'placement' => $placements[$i],
            'css'       => array(
                'top'    => $top1,
                'bottom' => $bottom1,
                'height' => $bottom1 - $top1;
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I can't actually test it, but I think it should leave you with a correct blocks array.

**Edit 1:** Doesn't seem to yield the required result, see comments below.

**Edit 2:** I think this is the exact same problem: [Visualization of calendar events. Algorithm to layout events with maximum width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311410/visualization-of-calendar-events-algorithm-to-layout-events-with-maximum-width). Someone solved it with C#, but it should be relatively easy to port that answer to PHP to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks alot for your effort, I'll test this tomorrow and return with the result.

Comment: I think I see what's going on. I just don't know how to fix it currently. If you look closely the blocks do get the expected numbers, just not the correct. For example, event #68 overlaps with #426 and #385, and thus gets size 1/3rd. However, #385 overlaps with #68, #383, #381 and #63, and gets size 1/5th. So the blocks do get the right size/position based on the amount of events they overlap with, however this ends up looking weird. Something to keep in mind is that an overlap between A+B and B+C does not necessarily mean an overlap between A+C. Maybe this can help you come up with something.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the exact same thing when I were experimenting with this yesterday. Thanks alot for the link, it does indeed look to be the exact same problem. I'll translate it to PHP and test it tomorrow - if it works I'll certainly share it here.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It ended up with some of the JavaScript provided from your link (http://jsbin.com/akudop/173/edit#javascript,html,live). Thanks alot for the help!