# How to arrange events for a daily calendar properly?

Tags: android, algorithm, calendar

Helo,

I've got a calendar view, which displays every hour amond each other.

Now I want to add some LinearLayouts, so that my Events in my calendar are added.

But now the problem: What if there are several Events at the same time?

The first problem is, that the green box has to fit the screen under the blue and yellow box.

The second problem is, that the violet box has to be shown at the first column if there is no space available.

Does anybody know a good algorithm to solve this problem?

Thank you.

[Calendar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9uQI.png)

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311410/visualization-of-calendar-events-algorithm-to-layout-events-with-maximum-width).